# Preciso montar uma consulta com MySql através do Laravel(Eloquent)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tenho que pegar dados de 3 tabelas(`planejamento_objetivo`, `planejamento` e `equipe`) e depois aplicar um filtro por período e equipe.

Montar a consulta para trazer os dados da tabela `planejamento_objetivo`.
Só vai trazer os objetivos que se referem ao período selecionado, e estiverem vinculado à coluna `planejamento_id`, que sejam da equipe em questão tabela (`planejamento` `equipe_id`) E que estejam vinculadas com um planejamento (coluna `situacao_planejamento_id`) com situação igual à 2.

```
public function selecionaDados(array $filtro = [])
    {

        $query = DB::table('planejamento_objetivo')
            ->join('planejamento', 'planejamento_objetivo.planejamento_id', '=', 'planejamento.id')
            ->join('fase', 'planejamento.fase_id', '=', 'fase.idFase')

            ->select('planejamento_objetivo.id AS id',
                     'planejamento_objetivo.objetivo AS objetivo',
                     'planejamento_objetivo.prazo AS prazo',
                     'planejamento_objetivo.situacao_planejamento_objetivo_id AS situacao',
                     'planejamento_objetivo.texto_report AS report'
                     )
            ->selectRaw('DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(prazo, "%m/%Y"), "%Y-%m") AS periodo')

            ->where('planejamento_objetivo.situacao_planejamento_objetivo_id', 2)
            ->orderBy('prazo', 'asc')
            ->get();

            return $query->toArray();
    }
```

Estou tendo mais dificuldades na hora de montar o filtro.

Agradeço se alguém puder me ajudar.

Comment: Pessoal, peço que, se não forem me ajudar, ao menos não despontuem minha pergunta. Sou iniciante e talvez p vocês isso é simples, mas para mim que estou iniciando ainda não é. Vocês passaram por essa fase, então peço a compreensão de vocês. Valeu

Comment: Na pergunta você fala em consulta com Eloquent, mas o código está em Query Builder. Passe um filtro via callback no método where.

Comment: Fiz isso e deu certo!! Desculpa por não saber formular direito minha dúvida. Sou novato! . 

Valeu pela dica!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver desta forma.

public function selecionaObjetivos(array $filtro = [])
{

```
    $query = DB::table('planejamento_objetivo')
        ->join('planejamento', 'planejamento_objetivo.planejamento_id', '=', 'planejamento.id')
        ->join('fase', 'planejamento.fase_id', '=', 'fase.idFase')
        ->join('situacao_planejamento_objetivo', 
            'planejamento_objetivo.situacao_planejamento_objetivo_id', '=', 'situacao_planejamento_objetivo.id')

        ->select('planejamento_objetivo.id AS id',
                 'planejamento_objetivo.objetivo AS objetivo',
                 'planejamento_objetivo.prazo AS prazo',
                 'planejamento_objetivo.situacao_planejamento_objetivo_id AS situacao',
                 'planejamento_objetivo.texto_report AS report',
                 'situacao_planejamento_objetivo.situacao AS descricaoSituacao'
                )
        ->where('planejamento_objetivo.situacao_planejamento_objetivo_id', 2)
        ->where('fase.IDPROJETO', $filtro['projeto_id']);
        if(!isset($filtro['fase_id'])) {
            $query->where('planejamento.fase_id', $filtro['fase_id']);
        }

        $periodoInicial = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/'.$filtro['filtro_periodo_inicial']);
        $periodoFinal = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/'.$filtro['filtro_periodo_final']);

        $periodosFormatados = [
            'inicial' => $periodoInicial->format('Y-m-d'),
            'final' => $periodoFinal->format('Y-m-d')
        ];

        $query->having('prazo', '>=', $periodosFormatados['inicial'])
        ->having('prazo', '<=', $periodosFormatados['final']);

        $query->orderBy('prazo', 'asc');

        return $query->get()->toArray();
}
```